# Why is my Angular app's polyfills.js 36kb when my browserslist is just `last 1 Chrome version`?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, polyfills

Here are the steps I took to create an example Angular app:

1. `npm i -g @angular/cli` (Installed Angular 11.2)
2. `ng new foo`
3. Opt in for SASS, Angular Router, and analytics
4. `cd foo`
5. Replace the contents of `.browserslistrc` with `last 1 Chrome version`. (Running `npx browserslist` then prints only `chrome 89`, as expected.)
6. `ng build --prod`

Here is the result:

```
$ ng build --prod
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.
✔ Copying assets complete.
✔ Index html generation complete.

Initial Chunk Files               | Names         |      Size
main.feaf6a85348d901578d8.js      | main          | 211.52 kB
polyfills.00096ed7d93ed26ee6df.js | polyfills     |  35.98 kB
runtime.7b63b9fd40098a2e8207.js   | runtime       |   1.45 kB
styles.09e2c710755c8867a460.css   | styles        |   0 bytes

                                  | Initial Total | 248.95 kB

Build at: 2021-03-16T14:41:16.954Z - Hash: 57aec26226ae3eb0ee1b - Time: 12529ms
```

I'm surprised that it compiles 36kb of polyfills when all I'm supporting is the latest version of Chrome. To my way of thinking, this should require few if any polyfills.

What do these 36kb do? It's hard for me to tell because the file is minified.

Comment: Why not open the file and check whatever it contains?

Comment: As I said, the file is minified so it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you remove `.browserlistrc` or comment out everything, you will get: `35.98 kB`.

With just that one line, `browserlist` falls back to the value of [`defaults`](https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist#full-list), which includes: `> 0.5%, last 2 versions, Firefox ESR, not dead`

Note that these default values are mainly relevant due to Zone.js support, as you can see for yourself. Try `ng build` without the `--prod` flag and you get a nicely commented polyfills file: (Showing first few lines only, for `.browserlistrc`: `last 1 Chrome version`)

```
/**
 * This file includes polyfills needed by Angular and is loaded before the app.
 * You can add your own extra polyfills to this file.
 *
 * This file is divided into 2 sections:
 *   1. Browser polyfills. These are applied before loading ZoneJS and are sorted by browsers.
 *   2. Application imports. Files imported after ZoneJS that should be loaded before your main^M
 *      file.
 *
 * The current setup is for so-called "evergreen" browsers; the last versions of browsers that
 * automatically update themselves. This includes Safari >= 10, Chrome >= 55 (including Opera),
 * Edge >= 13 on the desktop, and iOS 10 and Chrome on mobile.
 *
 * Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support
 */
```

Learn more in https://angular.io/guide/browser-support

Comment: Note that I didn't remove `browserslist`, I replaced its contents with `last 1 Chrome version`. Surely that shouldn't translate to `defaults`?

Comment: No, it only overrides the part which affects chrome, the others are not overridden

Comment: Generally tip: all `.*rc` files are written to _extend_ and override the previous default values, not replace them.

Comment: Hm, but when I run `npx browserslist` it only outputs `chrome 89`. You're saying that's not correct? I'm a little surprised if that's the case because it would mean Browserslist's behavior is rather misleading.

Comment: I get the same output for `npx browserslist` but that doesn't include the support that Zone.js needs for Angular itself. I have updated my answer to include that. But yes, you could say it's a bit misleading. Like I said, the rc files extend, not replace.

Comment: That seems like very strange behavior. Is there a way to override those defaults?

Comment: But yes, I confirm that removing `zone.js` from `polyfills.ts` does remove pretty much all the polyfills.